# Cannot implement $.data.promise

Tags: jaydata

When I am integrating 2 modules then I am getting the following error:

Not implemented!: $data.Promise.then

I spend 2 days working on it.On local server its working but on my local system this error is coming.

Here is my code:

```
function getSelectedGridData(viewId,filterId,groupId){

    // Declaration of variables
    var resultArray=[];
    var viewFieldArray=[];
    var headerArray=[];
    var headerString="";
    var groupString="";
    var innerFilterString="";
    var outerFilterString="";
    var swapFilter="";

    offlinedb.view.toArray(function (View) {
       ................some code...........
                // Fetch data from table 'document_header' and convert entity set into array
                offlinedb.document_headers.toArray(function (header){
                    ......some code............
                    });
    }).then(function (startGroup){
        offlinedb.grouping.toArray(function (Group) {
            ...some code.....                       
        }).then(function (startFilter){
            offlinedb.filters.toArray(function (Filter) {
                   ..some code............
            sqlitedb.transaction(function (sqliteTransation) {
                ...some code.....
            });
        });
});
}); 
}
```

My error is :

```
Not implemented!: $data.Promise.then

Exception {name: "Not implemented!", message: "$data.Promise.then", data: undefined, _getStackTrace: function}
 jaydata.js:1880
Guard.raise jaydata.js:1880
$data.Class.define.then jaydata.js:9239
getSelectedGridData common.js:72
(anonymous function) common.js:348
Uncaught Not implemented!: $data.Promise.then
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a promise libraray, jquery or q

Comment: I am using require.js and in that I have included both q.js and jquery.js in main.js

Comment: jaydata does not support require.js

Comment: then how the code is working in local server folder??
and the rest of the functions are working fine except this..

Answer (score 0):

put them in the shown order, it would work

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://include.jaydata.org/jaydata.js"></script>
```